# DynamoDB: Return multiple item or an Item?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have been reading about [Best Practices for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html) on AWS Documentation.

What I don't get why is it good idea to store multiple Items in the table for 1 Order for Order Detail and Product? I understand it is for access patterns to be searchable.  Why not keep in a single item? For example:

```
{
  "Id": "AAA-BB-45555",
  "Email": "name@hotmail.com",
  "UserId": "425",
  "Name": "John Paul",
  "Total": "12.50",
  "Billing": {
    "Name": "John Paul",
    "Address": {
      "Address1": "line1...",
      "Address2": "line2..."
    }
  },
  "Products": [
    {
      "ItemId": "AAABB",
      "Name": "Product 1"
    },
    {
      "ItemId": "AAVVV",
      "Name": "Product 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Query would return 1 Item of Order Detail (include Products), surely this is cheaper than having return multiple Items of Order Detail and Products?

Comment: I only skimmed through the link you provided and thus only commenting in lack of definitive answer. With your suggested model it AFAIK is not possible to fulfill all the access pattern requirements. For example `8: Get all Orderitems for a Product ...` and `12: Get inventory by Product and Warehouse`. Or you would need to do the operations on client code side instead.